# Check against multiple - if not - conditions in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have two input fields whit start and end time for an event. I only want the time to be in xx:00 or xx:30 format. Front-end is taken care of but I want in validate input in backend. Below is how I retrieve only minutes from posted time.

```
function validate_time($start_time,$end_time)
{
    $start_time_min = substr($start_time,-2,2);
    $end_time_min = substr($end_time,-2,2);

    if ($start_time_min != '00' || $end_time_min != '00')
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ($start_time_min != '30' || $end_time_min != '30')
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Above if statement returns always false, so what I need is to return false only if the start or end time is not 00 or not 30.

Comment: If the first condition isn't true, then the second will be; since a value can't be both `00` *and* `30`, one of the two will match. You'll probably want to combine this into one check: *is not `00` and is not `30`…*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single If condition like this code:

```
function validate_time($start_time,$end_time)
{
    $start_time_min = substr($start_time,-2,2);
    $end_time_min = substr($end_time,-2,2);    
    if (($start_time_min != '00' && $start_time_min != '30') || ($end_time_min != '00' && $end_time_min != '30'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Or just boil it down to a single `return ($stm == '00' || $stm == '30) && (...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Using or (`||`) in your above conditions is the cause of your problem as you will find one or the other is != 0 or 30.

```
if ($start_time_min != '00' && $start_time_min != '30')
{
    return false;
}
if ($end_time_min != '00' && $end_time_min != '30')
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct but I accept @nawin's answer as it is shorter.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function validate_time($start_time,$end_time)
{
   $startTime = explode(':', $start_time);
   $endTime = explode(':', $end_time);
   if ($startTime[1] !='00' || $endTime[1] !='30') {
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```